# What is the maximum possible length of a .NET string?

Tags: .net, string, limits

What is the longest string that can be created in .NET? The docs for the `String` class are silent on this question as far as I can see, so an authoritative answer might require some knowledge of internals. Would the maximum change on a 64-bit system?

[This is asked more for curiosity than for practical use - I don't intend to create any code that uses gigantic strings!]

Answer (score 401, accepted):

The theoretical limit may be 2,147,483,647, but the practical limit is nowhere near that. Since no single object in a .NET program may be over 2GB and the string type uses UTF-16 (2 bytes for each character), the best you could do is 1,073,741,823, but you're not likely to ever be able to allocate that on a 32-bit machine.

This is one of those situations where ["If you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong."](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070301-00/?p=27803)

Comment: This is the correct answer.  You're more likely to run out of memory before being able to allocate enough to exhaust the string length.  On a fresh boot you might be able to pull an allocation of 2GB (with 1M characters) as mentioned here, but that's all.

Comment: Assuming that your "no single object may be over 2Gb" assertion is accurate, this IS the theoretical limit as well as the practical one - the constraint on String length would be the total object size, not the capacity of the Length field.

Comment: If anyone is interested in the exact value, on my 64-bit machine it's 1,073,741,791 (1024 · 1024 · 1024 - 33) characters. See also [my related question about the exact max size of `byte[]`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6616739/41071).

Comment: I go crazy about answers that contain short but in depth explanation.

Comment: There is an option to allow .NET 4.5 (and later) objects to be larger than 2GB on 64-bit machines. [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087982/single-objects-still-limited-to-2-gb-in-size-in-clr-4-0)

Comment: @MikayilAbdullayev - `I go crazy ...` in a good way? or in a bad way? :) :) :)

Comment: By default, the maximum size of an Array is 2 gigabytes (GB).

In a 64-bit environment, you can avoid the size restriction by setting the enabled attribute of the gcAllowVeryLargeObjects configuration element to true in the run-time environment.

Comment: @bandybabboon  Yes, but strings are not array objects.  The documentation for gcAllowVeryLargeObjects also mentions that it does not pertain to strings.

Answer (score 78):

Based on my highly scientific and accurate experiment, it tops out on my machine well before 1,000,000,000 characters. (I'm still running the code below to get a better pinpoint).

**UPDATE:**
After a few hours, I've given up. Final results: Can go a lot bigger than 100,000,000 characters, instantly given `System.OutOfMemoryException` at 1,000,000,000 characters.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int i = 100000000;
        try
        {
            for (i = i; i <= int.MaxValue; i += 5000)
            {
                string value = new string('x', i);
                //WL(i);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            WL(i);
            WL(exc);
        }
        WL(i);
        RL();
    }

    #region Helper methods

    private static void WL(object text, params object[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text.ToString(), args);   
    }

    private static void RL()
    {
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }

    private static void Break() 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Applying a binary search here would probably help you find this answer a lot quicker...

Answer (score 52):

Since the `Length` property of `System.String` is an `Int32`, I would guess that that the maximum length would be 2,147,483,647 chars (max `Int32` size). If it allowed longer you couldn't check the Length since that would fail.

Comment: @m.edmondson: I'm not convinced actually. An [array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for instances has a `LongLength` as well and a stream uses `long` as length. Although it is valid answer, it's nood an accurate way to measure this.

Comment: But the first two bits are used for ASCII/non-ASCII indication as [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3377/Strings-UNDOCUMENTED) says, so it should be 2^30 = 1 073 741 824

Answer (score 35):

For anyone coming to this topic late, I could see that hitscan's "you probably shouldn't do that" might cause someone to ask what they should do…

The [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=VS.100).aspx) class is often an easy replacement.
Consider one of the [stream-based classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3352a4t(v=vs.110).aspx) especially, if your data is coming from a file.

The problem with `s += "stuff"` is that it has to allocate a completely new area to hold the data and then copy all of the old data to it plus the new stuff - EACH AND EVERY LOOP ITERATION. So, adding five bytes to 1,000,000 with `s += "stuff"` is extremely costly.
If what you want is to just write five bytes to the end and proceed with your program, you have to pick a class that leaves some room for growth:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(5000);
for (; ; )
    {
        sb.Append("stuff");
    }
```

`StringBuilder` will [auto-grow by doubling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495855/how-does-the-stringbuilder-decide-how-large-its-capacity-should-be) when it's limit is hit. So, you will see the growth pain once at start, once at 5,000 bytes, again at 10,000, again at 20,000. Appending strings will incur the pain every loop iteration.

Comment: It's ALSO worth noting that StringBuilder allows you to set the initial size. Useful if you know you're going to be using 10,000,000 entries ahead of time, allowing you to ignore some of the crunch.

Comment: +1 For seeing through the question and answering to good design. Comparatively, "this is how big your string can be before it blows", as opposed to, "if you REALLY need to store a lot of text, use this..."

Comment: For many corporate use cases such as exports, or logs that require processing and is above 2GB, the StringBuilder with its MaxValue that can go up to Int32 (2147483647) as per documentation, is not the solution. The same limitations remain.

Answer (score 15):

The max length of a string *on my machine* is **1,073,741,791**.

You see, Strings aren't limited by integer as is commonly believed.

Memory restrictions aside, Strings cannot have more than 2<sup>30</sup> (**1,073,741,824**) characters, since a 2GB limit is imposed by the Microsoft CLR (Common Language Runtime). 33 more than my computer allowed.

Now, here's something you're welcome to try yourself.

Create a new C# console app in Visual Studio and then copy/paste the main method here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("String test, by Nicholas John Joseph Taylor");

    Console.WriteLine("\nTheoretically, C# should support a string of int.MaxValue, but we run out of memory before then.");

    Console.WriteLine("\nThis is a quickish test to narrow down results to find the max supported length of a string.");

    Console.WriteLine("\nThe test starts ...now:\n");

    int Length = 0;

    string s = "";

    int Increment = 1000000000; // We know that s string with the length of 1000000000 causes an out of memory exception.

    LoopPoint:

    // Make a string appendage the length of the value of Increment

    StringBuilder StringAppendage = new StringBuilder();

    for (int CharacterPosition = 0; CharacterPosition < Increment; CharacterPosition++)
    {
        StringAppendage.Append("0");

    }

    // Repeatedly append string appendage until an out of memory exception is thrown.

    try
    {
        if (Increment > 0)
            while (Length < int.MaxValue)
            {
                Length += Increment;

                s += StringAppendage.ToString(); // Append string appendage the length of the value of Increment

                Console.WriteLine("s.Length = " + s.Length + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));

            }

    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryException ex) // Note: Any other exception will crash the program.
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + ex.Message + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") + ".");

        Length -= Increment;

        Increment /= 10;

        Console.WriteLine("After decimation, the value of Increment is " + Increment + ".");

    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + ex2.Message + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") + ".");

        Console.WriteLine("Press a key to continue...");

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    if (Increment > 0)
    {
        goto LoopPoint;

    }

    Console.WriteLine("Test complete.");

    Console.WriteLine("\nThe max length of a string is " + s.Length + ".");

    Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue.");

    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

My results were as follows:

> String test, by Nicholas John Joseph Taylor
>
> Theoretically, C# should support a string of int.MaxValue, but we run
>   out of memory before then.
>
> This is a quickish test to narrow down results to find the max
>   supported length of a string.
>
> The test starts ...now:
>
> s.Length = 1000000000 at 08/05/2019 12:06
>
> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. at
>   08/05/2019 12:06. After decimation, the value of Increment is
>   100000000.
>
> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. at
>   08/05/2019 12:06. After decimation, the value of Increment is
>   10000000. s.Length = 1010000000 at 08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length = 1020000000 at 08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length = 1030000000 at 08/05/2019
>   12:06 s.Length = 1040000000 at 08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length = 1050000000
>   at 08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length = 1060000000 at 08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length
>   = 1070000000 at 08/05/2019 12:06
>
> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. at
>   08/05/2019 12:06. After decimation, the value of Increment is 1000000.
>   s.Length = 1071000000 at 08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length = 1072000000 at
>   08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length = 1073000000 at 08/05/2019 12:06
>
> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. at
>   08/05/2019 12:06. After decimation, the value of Increment is 100000.
>   s.Length = 1073100000 at 08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length = 1073200000 at
>   08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length = 1073300000 at 08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length =
>   1073400000 at 08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length = 1073500000 at 08/05/2019
>   12:06 s.Length = 1073600000 at 08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length = 1073700000
>   at 08/05/2019 12:06
>
> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. at
>   08/05/2019 12:06. After decimation, the value of Increment is 10000.
>   s.Length = 1073710000 at 08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length = 1073720000 at
>   08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length = 1073730000 at 08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length =
>   1073740000 at 08/05/2019 12:06
>
> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. at
>   08/05/2019 12:06. After decimation, the value of Increment is 1000.
>   s.Length = 1073741000 at 08/05/2019 12:06
>
> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. at
>   08/05/2019 12:06. After decimation, the value of Increment is 100.
>   s.Length = 1073741100 at 08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length = 1073741200 at
>   08/05/2019 12:06 s.Length = 1073741300 at 08/05/2019 12:07 s.Length =
>   1073741400 at 08/05/2019 12:07 s.Length = 1073741500 at 08/05/2019
>   12:07 s.Length = 1073741600 at 08/05/2019 12:07 s.Length = 1073741700
>   at 08/05/2019 12:07
>
> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. at
>   08/05/2019 12:07. After decimation, the value of Increment is 10.
>   s.Length = 1073741710 at 08/05/2019 12:07 s.Length = 1073741720 at
>   08/05/2019 12:07 s.Length = 1073741730 at 08/05/2019 12:07 s.Length =
>   1073741740 at 08/05/2019 12:07 s.Length = 1073741750 at 08/05/2019
>   12:07 s.Length = 1073741760 at 08/05/2019 12:07 s.Length = 1073741770
>   at 08/05/2019 12:07 s.Length = 1073741780 at 08/05/2019 12:07 s.Length
>   = 1073741790 at 08/05/2019 12:07
>
> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. at
>   08/05/2019 12:07. After decimation, the value of Increment is 1.
>   s.Length = 1073741791 at 08/05/2019 12:07
>
> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. at
>   08/05/2019 12:07. After decimation, the value of Increment is 0. Test
>   complete.
>
> The max length of a string is 1073741791.
>
> Press any key to continue.

The max length of a string on my machine is 1073741791.

I'd appreciate it very much if people could post their results as a comment below.

It will be interesting to learn if people get the same or different results.

Comment: "You see, Strings aren't limited by integer as is commonly believed." --> an integer in c# can go up to 2,147,483,647 and your result is very close (32 bytes less) to this value divided by two, which is logical as every character of a String is store as Unicode on two bytes. So even if the limit isn't imposed by the size of the integer, it's remarkably close to it.

Comment: Thanks for your code. I manage to reproduce it on OSX with ARM M1, .net 3.1:

The max length of a string is 1073741791.

Answer (score 2):

Since `String.Length` is an integer (that is an alias for `Int32`), its size is limited to `Int32.MaxValue` unicode characters. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

200 megs... at which point your app grinds to a virtual halt, has about a gig working set memory, and the o/s starts to act like you'll need to reboot.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "hello world";
    for(;;)
    {
        s = s + s.Substring(0, s.Length/10);
        Console.WriteLine(s.Length);
    }
}

12
13
14
15
16
17
18
...
158905664
174796230
192275853
211503438
```

Comment: I'm not sure the behavior you'd get from creating just one really big string is the same as what you're seeing by allocating a bunch of them and concatenating.

Answer (score -1):

String allocates dynamic memory size in the heap of your RAM.  But string address is stored in stack that occupies 4 bytes of memory.

Comment: This depends on the size of a reference. On 32-bit computers, 4 bytes is right. On 64-bit computers, it is 8 bytes.