# vb.net 2008 textbox max length

Tags: vb.net

What is the maximum amount of characters that can be put into a textbox in vb.net 2008?

Comment: Which namesapce are we talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Windows Forms:

[TextBox.MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength.aspx)

You can use this property to restrict the length of text entered in the control for values such as postal codes and telephone numbers. You can also use this property to restrict the length of text entered when the data is to be stored in a database so that the text entered into the control does not exceed the maximum length of the corresponding field in the database.

This property does not affect characters that are added programmatically.

When this property is set to 0, **the maximum length of the text that can be entered in the control is limited only by available memory**.

---

(But it's not a good idea to put so much data into a textbox that it fills all available memory. If you have that much data, you will need a different user interface. The TextBox was not designed for easily viewing/editing such large amounts of data.)

Comment: Is this not limited by the size of an in32?

Comment: Yes, in fact I think the limit will be set by the maximum length of A String which is about 1 billion character. From here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string

Comment: Very thorough answer for such a simple question. +1