# How many bytes can a textbox display?

Tags: c#

I have made my program using Visual Studio.

I would like a TextBox to display the contents of file, but when the contents of file reaches hundreds of megabytes in size, a `SystemOutOfMemoryException` message appears.

How many bytes can fit into a textbox? So that I can limit the size of the data I read from the file.

Comment: Displaying several hundred megabytes in a single Textbox is not going to make for a good user experience. Perhaps you should look at doing this a different way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [vb.net 2008 textbox max length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810865/vb-net-2008-textbox-max-length)

Comment: "How much the number of bytes that can fit a textbox" - How much free memory does the computer have at that time?

Comment: @MikeW unless the OP is creating a notepad-like application.

Comment: Oh yes - several hundred megabytes in Notepad is a wonderful experience.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a memory problem not a textbox problem which should have effectively unlimited capacity - max size of string = 2GB.

A dirty way is to catch the OOM exception and try again with half the size or so. Perhaps you can break it into smaller sections and store them in a temporary file to be loaded on demand.

If it's a really demanding application you can also target x64 or AnyCPU to get access to more memory on 64 bit Windows.