# What is the maximum size for a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the maximum possible length of a .NET string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string)

I need to know how many characters a string can contain in C#?

Is it the same as the max length of a char array?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string

Answer (score 16):

[String.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx) is an int so the its size is `2,147,483,647`. But consider using [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) if you find yourself asking this question !