# Characters limitation in INI file?

Tags: ini

Are there any known **characters** limitation for a value string that I have to put into INI file?

I currently have a line with 1800 characters, and I consider to extend it and save another 200 characters on this line. Does it make sense?

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file) but it does not mention a relevant limitation (it talks about 32K limitation of the file size, which is not my case).

Thank you!

Comment: not likely. have you tried it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486261/does-c-sharp-string-has-length-limit

Comment: I see it's probably 2^31. Thanks!