# How does the StringBuilder decide how large its capacity should be?

Tags: c#, clr

I know that the StringBuilder object allocates more memory when you use sb.Append(..) when the sb is already at capacity. But how much does that capacity increase?

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(5);
    sb.Append("0123456789");
```

Now what is the capacity of sb and why? What is the multiplier?

Just for clarity. I am asking about capacity and not length.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The capacity doubles each time apart from some special cases:

- If doubling is not enough then the capacity is further increased to the exact amount that is required.
- There is an upper limit - 0x7fffffff.

You can see the algorithm by using .NET Reflector or downloading the reference source.

I can't post the source code for the official .NET implementation but here's the code for the Mono implementation:

```
// Try double buffer, if that doesn't work, set the length as capacity
if (size > capacity) {

    // The first time a string is appended, we just set _cached_str
    // and _str to it. This allows us to do some optimizations.
    // Below, we take this into account.
    if ((object) _cached_str == (object) _str && capacity < constDefaultCapacity)
        capacity = constDefaultCapacity;

    capacity = capacity << 1;  // This means "capacity *= 2;"

    if (size > capacity)
        capacity = size;

    if (capacity >= Int32.MaxValue || capacity < 0)
        capacity = Int32.MaxValue;

    if (capacity > _maxCapacity && size <= _maxCapacity)
        capacity = _maxCapacity;
}
```

I would also recommend that you don't write code that relies on this specific algorithm as it is an implementation detail, and not something that is guaranteed by the interface.

Comment: Didn't Reflector start charging? :)

Comment: @Nick only the pro version (which is well worth the cost, FYI)

Comment: @Mark: Please do not post framework code obtained with Reflector.  Aside from this being a copyright violation, this is a problem for those of us working on other .NET runtimes, where [clean-room reimplementation is required](http://www.mono-project.com/Contributing).

Comment: @Mark: Thanks. I'm sure Mono's StringBuilder implementation is pretty much complete by now, and therefore the code won't hurt too much, but I just wanted to point this out for future reference.

Comment: @cdhowie: Is it legal to post the Mono implementation instead?

Comment: @Mark: Absolutely. Mono's implementations of the framework libraries are made available under the terms of the MIT license, which is pretty close to "do whatever you want with this."  [Here's Mono's implementation](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Text/StringBuilder.cs).

Comment: @cdhowie don't mean to be cheeky but I posted a question re. publishing framework code a while ago. You have some interesting thoughts, perhaps you'd like to add to it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109357/is-it-legal-to-make-code-decompiled-from-net-libraries-publicly-available

Comment: @chibacity: The top answer is pretty much spot on. I will add a comment about alternate framework contributors.

Answer (score 0):

It's exponential growth (specifically, doubling with each reallocation), in order to allow a series of appends to take O(N) time instead of O(N²) time.