# StringBuilder: AppendFormat and Capacity

Tags: c#, .net

In this code I try to `appendFormat` a message with a length bigger than the string builder's capacity:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(10);
        sb.AppendFormat("1234567890123"); // 13 characters
        Console.WriteLine(sb.Capacity);
    }
```

Do you know what should be the output (answer at the bottom)?

Okay, let's try to change this code and init `StringBuilder` with capacity, still less than the string length, for example 12:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(12);
        sb.AppendFormat("1234567890123"); // 13 characters
        Console.WriteLine(sb.Capacity);
    }
```

So, my question is: does `AppendFormat` really `double` the start capacity of `StringBuilder` if string couldn't be appened? If the appended string's length should be 24 characters, then the `Capacity` will become `48`?

Output code: **20** & **24**

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does it matter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the StringBuilder decide how large its capacity should be?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495855/how-does-the-stringbuilder-decide-how-large-its-capacity-should-be)

Comment: Thx for duplicate topic.

Comment: @Matt Davis, this is a question from interview :(

Comment: If you want to prevent the capactiy from expanding, you want to set StringBuilder.MaxCapacity.

Comment: @Peter, yeah, i know it. Just wanted to understand, how does capacity changing in AppendFormat method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does AppendFormat really double the start capacity of StringBuilder if the string couldn't be appended?

Yes -- [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

> Whenever the append operation causes the length of the StringBuilder object to exceed its capacity, its existing capacity is doubled and the Append operation succeeds.

Comment: Yeah, `capacity = capacity << 1;  // This means "capacity *= 2;"`  that's the answer