# Is there any limitations on length of the text in CommandText

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am wondering is there some limitation on the length of the text I can give to `CommandText`  field ?

I am using `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link [Mysql Dataprovider](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommand-commandtext)

`Commandtext` property defined as

```
public string CommandText {get; set;}
```

So limitation is same as limitation of length of a string. Check this post for string length limitation
[What is the maximum possible length of a .NET string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string)

Comment: I am afraid this is not correct. Just try to execute a command with a very long string and check. It will be truncated and cause exception

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow, post a separate question for this with your findings, exception and sample code as to what have you tried. fyi, size is limited by hardware configuration