# Retrieving VARCHAR(MAX)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

How can I retrieve a column of datatype `Varchar(MAX)` from a SQL Server database in C#?

I don't think `SqlDataReader` helps retrieve it.

Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: I tried retrieving it using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); But I read it that it needs to be retrieved using Streams/Pointers/Something and the traditional approach doesn't work

Comment: System.String is all you need

Comment: @Joy - how *big* is the data; if it is enormous, there are some things you might need to do differently...

Comment: off topic, In case its xml data you can check out [`ExecuteXmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executexmlreader.aspx)

Comment: Check here.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399384.aspx  In my experience with C# and stored procedures I have to specify the size as -1 for the parameter.  Other than that, pretty much works like a regular nvarchar or varchar parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a string field .... just grab it like any other string.....

```
// define your query
string query = "SELECT YourField FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE ID = 1";

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("......"))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
   conn.Open();

   using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
       if(rdr.Read())
       {
          string fieldValue = rdr.GetString(0);
       }
   }

   conn.Close();
}
```

There's really nothing special about the `VARCHAR(MAX)` type - it's just a text field, and it can hold up to 2 GB of text - just like a .NET `string`. You don't need to do anything special, like streaming or anything - just read the column into a string!

Comment: Although, if it turns out to be 500MB you might *choose* to read it via the streaming API

Comment: @Marc Gravell: yes, sure - but how many VARCHAR(MAX) columns do you really have that hold 500 MB of data?

Comment: I think there's a practical limit on how big a .NET string can be that is lower than [2 GB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string).

Comment: @marc_s Bro it works. Thank you. But I am just curious that will it work using SqlDataAdapter ?

Comment: I would like to undo my downvote, but stackoverflow won't allow it. I initially thought that this approach will truncate (without warning) the retrieved string to a length of 2033 - but that applies when the query returns an `[xml]` column type - not `nvarchar(max)`.

Answer (score 0):

[Working with Large-Value Types in ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399384.aspx)

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
while (reader.Read())
{
    SqlChars buffer = reader.GetSqlChars(0);
}
```

Or just convert it to CLR type:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
     string str = reader[0].ToString();
     Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```