# Limitations of string variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Base64 jpeg image string which is a simple signature image. I can store the string in SQL Server and retreive it, but when I try to pass it to a method or save in a Session variable I get null value. Is there a limit to the string you can pass to a method or save in a session var?

Here is the code;

I get the string from db,

```
      string VSignature = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SignatureB64"];

// VSignature gets valued ok
// then passed to a class with method to handle image,

      Write.GetPageOneReadyToBeAltered(f_older + "\\FDD.PDF", f_older + @"\N.PDF", 
            CertID, VSignature);
```

//here VSignature is null

```
      public static void GetPageOneReadyToBeAltered(string PageNReader, string PageNStamper, string CertificateNo, string VSignature)
        {
        // prepare page one's copy to be altered by user  

        PdfReader pdfreader = new PdfReader(PageNReader);
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfreader, new FileStream(PageNStamper, FileMode.Create));
            /*
             some pdf stuff done here, irrelevant
            */
            var pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1);

             byte[] bytSig1 = Convert.FromBase64String(VSignature);

            MemoryStream msSig1 = new MemoryStream(bytSig1);
            iTextSharp.text.Image sig1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(msSig1);
            sig1.SetAbsolutePosition(23, 76);
            sig1.ScaleToFit(60f, 60f);
            pdfContentByte.AddImage(sig1);
       }
```

thanks

Comment: 'Passing to a method' should always work. Your problem is not where you think it is.

Comment: There's always a limit for a session variable, your server's memory. But apart from that, show us your code where you get the string and where you store/read the session variable.

Comment: And the relation between VSignature and VetSignature is ... >

Comment: just missed it when removing irrelevant code, I know it is not an issue. thanks for the heads up though :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for their time, I think this is something unique to the way my app moves between different aspx pages, so I will keep all the inputs in mind. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you blew the limits for string sizes, you wouldn't just get a null value back - you'd get an exception. It's *far* more likely that you're doing something wrong in your code, but you haven't shown it to us so it's hard to say what.

Basically, while there *are* limitations (around a billion characters, IIRC) it's very unlikely that you're running into them.

Answer (score 1):

This is unlikely to be related to the image size (unless you're using huge images), and anyway you should receive an Exception, nut a null value...

see also here: [What is the maximum possible length of a .NET string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string)