# Storing large flat file text to a string

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, file

Is it possible to store the text of a large flat file(size approximately 10 mb) to a string in vb.net?

Comment: Sure it is.  What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, it is possible (but 10 MB is not really "large"). Did you try something that didn't work? Maybe you could show us and we could help you get that working.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your responses. I am currently working on a project and am storing the text of large flat files on a string and then creating an array out of that string. i have not faced any problem yet(fingers crossed!!) but just wanted to be sure if it would not pose any problem in the future.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is in fact a function in the base class library that can do exactly this: [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)

```
Dim text = File.ReadAllText("path/to/file")
```

Comment: Thanks Martinho..  i am currently using a stream reader to read the flat file and then creating an array list out of the streamreader and then store array elements to a single string.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum size of a string depends on lots of variables and will be different on every machine.

I found a good explanation on [this site](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/maximum-string-length-c-and-net-t2539908.html)

*"The maximum size of all reference type (like a string) instances is limited
by the CLR to 2GB, that means that a string can hold a maximum of ~1G
characters.
While it's possible to reach that limit when running on a 64 bit OS, you
will never be able to create such large strings (or arrays) on a 32 bit OS.
The reason is that you won't have that amount of "contiguous" address space
available to create the backing store (a char array) for the string."*

The accepted answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string) would echo the above explanation