# How much text can you store into a Desire2Learn Text-type grade object?

Tags: desire2learn

When I create a Text type GradeObject in the Desire2Learn Learning Environment, how much text can go into the grade object's associated value?

Answer (score 1):

While the grade value for a Text-type GradeObject gets handled through the Learning Framework API as a [.NET  string type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string), when the value gets stored in the LE database, its size is currently constrained to 100 characters.