# Writing a text file into a gz file using GZipStream without first writing the text file to disk

Tags: c#, stream, compression, gzipstream

Im currently generating a large output from a few database queries. The resulting XML file is about 2GB. (This is a years worth of data).
To save some disk space and download time for the client i am adding this file into a compressed file using the GZipStream class. See below for how i am currently compressing the file into a gz. NOTE: the fi object is a FileInfo.

```
using (FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead())
using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(fi.FullName + ".gz"))
using (GZipStream Compress = new GZipStream(outFile, CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    int numRead;
    while ((numRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        Compress.Write(buffer, 0, numRead);
    }
}
```

This method works fine but requires me to write out the 2GB text file to disk and then read it all back in again in order to add it to the GZipStream and then write it back out again as a compressed file. It seems like a waste of time.

Is there a way to add my 2GB string directly to the GZipStream without first having to write to the disk?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: I want to be able to write my 2GB string directly into a text file within a compressed gz file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's any way you can get the database result into a string and then load it into a MemoryStream you should be alright:

```
        var databaseResult = "<xml>Very Long Xml String</xml>";

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.Write(databaseResult);
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Position = 0;

                using (var outFile = File.Create(@"c:\temp\output.xml.gz"))
                using (var Compress = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(outFile, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[65536];
                    int numRead;
                    while ((numRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        Compress.Write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Realized after some more testing that you will run out of memory if you run the entire 2Gb result into a string, the maxium capacity of a string is apparently 1 Gb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string

Answer (score 13):

You can create a `StreamWriter` (or in your case maybe a `XmlWriter`) from the `GZipStream` and just write to it instead.

```
using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(fi.FullName + ".gz"))
using (GZipStream compress = new GZipStream(outFile, CompressionMode.Compress))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(compress))
{
    foreach(string line in GetLines())
        writer.WriteLine(line);
}
```