# How to handle out of memory exception string builder

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, stringbuilder, streamwriter

I have this method that is expected to return a string but the string is pretty big maybe in GB. Currently this runs into out of memory exception.

I was thinking I would write to a file (random filename) then read it delete the file and send back the response. Tried `MemoryStream` and `StreamWriter` that too ran into out of memory exception.

Did not want to initialize `StringBuilder` with a capacity since the size was not known and I think it needs a continuous block of memory.

What is the best course of action to solve this problem?

```
    public string Result()
    {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= Int.Max; i++)
        {
            response.Append("keep adding some text {0}", i);
            response.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        return response.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show real code?

Comment: If you used StreamWriter, and it's backing strategy was to write to memory then, yes, you would get a OutOfMemory exception.  You might try using a file stream, such as one that writes to the operating system's transient store (e.g., the `temp` directory).  If performance is not a concern, you can simply call `Flush()` on the file stream after you write to it.  Though, one wouldn't be wrong suggesting that you just write straight to a file in that case, with no buffering.

Comment: It is better to store the records piece by piece than dumping them together. Do you have code where you use the `Result()`?

Comment: How are you sending back the response? If this is a web service, you could always write straight to the response stream...

Answer (score 4):

Even if you could solve the memory problem on the `StringBuilder`, the resulting string by calling `response.ToString()` would be larger than the maximum length of a string in .NET, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/140749/3997704

So you will have to make your function store its result elsewhere, like in a file.