# Index of the string can be long?

Tags: c#

I want to know whether we can give the index of the string as Long data type.

```
    var i=long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    var result = testString[i-1];
```

the second line giving me the error by saying that "The best overloaded method match for 'string.this[int]' has some invalid arguments."

Comment: what is `testString` here?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/140749/3456453) should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't use long for most collection types (you haven't specified what testString is).

One way to get around this would be to segregate the string into a multi-part / multi-dimension array then use a multiplier to get which part of the array to check.

For example: 
Your index is 100,000 and you have an array of shorts (32,767 length)...

```
string[,] testString = new string[100, 32766]; //Replace this with your Initialisation / existing string
var arrayRank = (int)Math.Round((double) 100000 / 32767, 0);
var arrayIndex = (int)Math.Round((double)100000 % 32767, 0);

//Test this works.
//testString[arrayRank, arrayIndex] = "test"; - Test to see that the array range is assignable.
var result = testString[arrayRank, arrayIndex]; //Test value is what we expect
```

This may not be the most efficient way to go about things, but it is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot accept a `long`. The only overload accepts an `int` indexer. You would need to change your code to `int.Parse()` instead of `long.Parse()`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass long as an index of array, compiler doesn't allow that.

Workaround can be converting the long to int, this is called narrow conversion.

```
var result= testString[(int)i)];
```

Comment: the correct syntax for casting would be `(int)i` not `int(i)`

Comment: This won't even compile

Comment: Corrected the syntax... Thank you