# Optimal/Secure string length in Web APIs

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, owasp

I was looking at different ways to secure .Net RESTful Web API When I came across this [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Input_validation) link.

One of the recommendation under Input Validation:

> - Validate input: length / range / format and type

I start thinking about adding a constraint to all string attributes in view models. But, one of the requirement from customers is to have no limit for string lengths.
To face this trade-off, I need to figure out a number (string length maximum) that could be:

- Secure: does not make Web APIs fail or make backend code run out of memory.
- Unlimited: looks like unlimited string to end user.

I know that there is no such a thing "[unlimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string)", but I'm really looking for number here that is commonly used by developers in such a scenario.

Comment: That is a great question, but unfortunately there is no 'right answer'. Your customers are literally asking for the impossible. You can't achieve it. You need to pick a length that is reasonable given your business and communicate it to them.

Comment: Side comment: have a look at [this article](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/03/07/functional-c-primitive-obsession/) on how you could implement a safe application-wide constraint on all your strings.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out what your longest possible JSON string is and then limit it to that

Comment: I saw an article somewhere saying emails cannot be longer than 254 characters, if this helps for email fields. It all depends on the field.