# What SQL data type length should xs:string map to when no maxLength is defined?

Tags: sql-server, xsd

Searched the Web, but didn't find a clear answer to the question.

Let's say I have an element and there's no maxLength property defined:

```
<xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string">
</xs:element>
```

Should this element map to nvarchar(MAX) SQL data type?

Comment: Is this data going directly into your database (if so, why not into an `xml` column)? If not, what's doing the *processing* and what limitations does that apply?

Comment: Thanks for answer. No, the data isn't going directly into the database. Let's say I just remove the white-spaces on the sides.

Comment: So, if you're doing that in e.g. [tag:c#] then that already imposes a [2GB limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string) so `nvarchar(max)` seems reasonable.