# IIS Hang when reading XML with StreamReader in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, freeze, filestream, streamreader

Our diagnostic service said there was a hang at this position of our code.  Is there anything that is shown that could cause a hang when reading a XML file with StreamReader?

```
STACK_TEXT:  
000000e1`8225cef8 00007ffa`b93f8eb8     : 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 00007ffa`b1ef6cdf 000000e1`8225cdd8 : ntdll!NtReadFile+0xa
000000e1`8225cf00 00007ffa`b0b3c9c8     : 00000000`00001000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000018 000000e1`8225d098 : KERNELBASE!ReadFile+0x74
000000e1`8225cf80 00007ffa`b0a8e803     : 000000e3`d59a39d8 000000e3`d5b65b00 000000e3`d59a3ea8 00000000`00000400 : mscorlib_ni+0x63c9c8
000000e1`8225d060 00007ffa`b0a8e75d     : 000000e3`d5ec4bd8 00000000`00001000 00000000`00000000 000000ee`f3acbb90 : mscorlib_ni!System.IO.FileStream.ReadFileNative+0x83
000000e1`8225d0c0 00007ffa`b0a8e68a     : 00000000`00000000 000000e3`d5b65b30 000000e3`d5b65300 00007ffa`b0a775db : mscorlib_ni!System.IO.FileStream.ReadCore+0x5d
000000e1`8225d130 00007ffa`b0b082d4     : 000000e3`d5b65b30 00007ffa`b0a8e898 00000000`00000001 000000e3`d59a39f8 : mscorlib_ni!System.IO.FileStream.Read+0x13a
000000e1`8225d190 00007ffa`b0b09fab     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00007ffa`b1f30d35 000000e1`8225cef8 : mscorlib_ni!System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer+0x44
000000e1`8225d1e0 00007ffa`57ffff6d     : 00007ffa`b05a5188 00000000`00000004 000000e3`d598bf58 00007ffa`52e4d508 : mscorlib_ni!System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd+0x8b
000000e1`8225d230 00007ffa`57fe774a     : 000000e3`d598bf58 000000e3`d59a3688 fffffff8`00000004 00000000`00000000 : Tournaments_Services!Tournaments.Services.Statistics.StatCrewService.ParseXml+0xbd
```

**Code**

```
private IGameCastGame ParseXml(string fileLocation, StatisticsType statisticsType)
{
    XDocument xDocument;

    try
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(
            fileLocation,
            FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read,
            FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                xDocument = XDocument.Parse(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex);
        return null;
    }

    return StatCrewGame.Create(xDocument, statisticsType).Parse();
}
```

Comment: A way to large XML File?

Comment: Stack trace says there's a problem reading the file, nothing to do with parsing the XML.

Comment: Why are you doing `XDocument.Parse(streamReader.ReadToEnd())` instead of [`XDocument.Load(streamReader)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load?view=net-7.0#system-xml-linq-xdocument-load(system-io-textreader))?  Reading the XML into a temporary string will be much less memory-efficient than not doing so.  And if the XML file is large you might hit the [effective string length limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/140468) on your system.

Comment: Also, why `FileShare.ReadWrite` and not `FileShare.Read`?  What do you want to happen if some other process modifies the file as you are reading it?

Comment: Well this file is written to at the same time as its being read by thousands of users.  I updated to `XDocument.Load(streamReader)` for now.  Not sure why I did that before.  These are not large files.

Comment: @dbc I have people writing to the same file as people reading.  What would be a better approach then?

Comment: *Well this file is written to at the same time as its being read by thousands of users.* -- I reckon the better approach would be to use a database.  As it is, if one process writes while others are reading, the results are unpredictable.  From the point of view of the readers, the file may look corrupt because it gets overwritten partway through.

Comment: Yes I handle corrupt XML by just storing the valid xml in cache until a fresh, valid xml is available.