# Create blank text file based on pre defind size using powershell

Tags: powershell

Using the below code, I a trying to create a blank text file

```
$fileSizeInKB = $File_size_for_warning / 1KB
$filePath = "C:\Testfile.txt"
New-Item -Path $filePath -ItemType File -Value ([char]0) * $fileSizeInKB
```

**$File_size_for_warning** is having byte value of `45883181261`

I am getting the below error while executing the code

```
New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '*'.
At E:\Monitoring_Test.ps1:126 char:1
+ New-Item -Path $filePath -ItemType File -Value ([char]0) * $fileSizeI ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

Please let me know what is wrong here and is there any other way to do this

Comment: @zett42: Thanks for that. but now getting error `The operation '[System.Char] * [System.Double]' is not defined.`

Answer (score 1):

As the file size is **large** (~43 GiB), you should use a different approach. Your current approach would create a string of this size entirely in memory before writing it to a file. This isn't even possible because the [maxium size of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/140749/7571258) is much lower. Even if it were possible you would not want to waste so much memory.

Using the [.NET file system API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.setlength?view=net-7.0) it is possible to create a blank file of any size much more efficiently, without the memory overhead:

```bash
$File_size_for_warning = 45883181261
$filePath = "C:\Testfile.txt"

# Create a file of 0 bytes using PowerShell to convert its path to a full path for
# use with .NET API. If you can ensure that $filePath is always a full path,
# then you don't need this step.
$filePath = (New-Item $filePath -Force).Fullname

# Open the file using .NET API.
$file = [IO.File]::Create( $filePath )
try {
    # Adjust the file size using .NET API. It will be automatically 
    # filled with null bytes.
    $file.SetLength( $File_size_for_warning )
}
finally {
    # Make sure the file is closed even in case of an exception.
    $file.Close()
}
```

---

Regarding your current approach, it would be generally fine for **small to medium size** files (up to around 1 GiB), but there are several errors that need to be fixed:

- Instead of specifying the size in KB, you should use the **byte size** `$File_size_for_warning`. The multiplication operator expects an `int` when the LHS argument is a string or array.
- The multiplication operator requires an **array or a string** in this context, so you need to convert the `char` to `string` or specify the null byte directly in a string, as shown in the example below.
- Finally you need to **add parentheses around the expression** that is used as an argument. Arguments of PowerShell commands are parsed in *[argument mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.4#argument-mode)*, to use expressions you need to force PowerShell into *expression mode* by using parentheses. Only a few simple expressions like accessing variables are understood by the parser when in argument mode.

```bash
New-Item -Path $filePath -ItemType File -Value ("`0" * $File_size_for_warning)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. but still I am getting error
`Cannot convert value "45881264333" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."`

Comment: @snehasishnandy I didn't notice that the file size is so large. In this case you need a different approach, see updated answer.